WinUI3 executable won't launch app when installed with setup project
I'm using a Windows Setup Project to make a .msi installer for my WinUI3 app. The app launches with the executable directly from the project output, but won't launch when installed with the msi installer.
I've copied the project output myself to program files and the executable works.
From Windows Event Viewer when I launch the installed app:
Faulting module name: Microsoft.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 3.1.6.0, time stamp: 0xeb72d9fd
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x0000000000009125
Faulting process id: 0x0x4518
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1DB352BA919EF80
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\USDA-dev\EFH-2\EFH2.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\USDA-dev\EFH-2\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.dll
Report Id: f2e31dbc-9f0b-4b22-9560-0d0f42b19a8d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 


I have had some issues recently with a WinU3 application which terminated in visual studio without generating any exceptions. My only solution was to comment out code test and uncomment until I got to the bottom of the issue.
